# CSS Transparency on background affects content

Tags: css, transparency

I have a div with CSS properties like so:

```
div.header {
    opacity:0.4;
    filter:alpha(opacity=40);
    background:#000;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
}
```

The problem is the content that is inside this div also has the same transparency. How can I only have the background color/div show the transparency without affecting the content inside that div?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `rgba` on your background:

```css
div.header {
    /* Fallback for web browsers that doesn't support RGBa */
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);

    /* RGBa with 0.6 opacity */
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);

    /* For IE 5.5 - 7*/
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#66000000, endColorstr=#66000000);

    /* For IE 8*/
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#66000000, endColorstr=#66000000)";
}
```

The color for IE is calculated by formula:

```
Math.floor(0.4 * 255).toString(16); // 0.4 is your desired opacity
```

it gives you `66` so that becomes the first 2 digits of the color.

[Source](http://robertnyman.com/2010/01/11/css-background-transparency-without-affecting-child-elements-through-rgba-and-filters/)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `rgba` colors:

```
div.header {
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
}
```

Comment: +1 You should declare an `rgb` property _before_ the rgba for browsers that don't do `rgba` and you can use the [Gradient Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532997%28VS.85%29.aspx) for versions of IE that don't support `rgba`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set background with rgba `background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);` where `0.6` is like opacity. Or put background with opacity in some div and then inside of that div create another div with content and with no opacity.